# Plotting a 3D surface with no interpolation?

Tags: r, plot, interpolation, rgl, geometry-surface

I have a following data:

```
library(rgl)
x <- c(rep(1,6),
       rep(3,6),
       rep(6,6),
       rep(9,6),
       rep(12,6))
y <- c(1.35,1.39,1.48,1.29,1.35,1.32,
       NA,1.5,1.44,1.6,1.5,1.41,
       NA,NA,1.72,1.56,1.6,1.55,
       NA,NA,NA,1.95,1.9,1.75,
       NA,NA,NA,NA,2.05,1.95)
z <- rep(1:6,5)
open3d()
plot3d(x,y,z, type = 'n')
lines3d(x,y,z)
```

Which is plotting lines in 3d as I expect.
But I cannot get it to plot a surface3d.
As I already read some threads I might need to interpolate my data. RGL docs has not cover this subject well. I tried akima but it doesn't accept NA's.
I would like to link lines to create a surface in linear way. I aware of the NA, so I expect that surface will be decreasing in the area for bigger x (more NA's).
Do I need to perform interpolation? If yes, how to do that on my sample data?
If no, how to achieve the surface3d on my sample data?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know where your x, y and z data come from originally, bu there is `surface3d` in `rgl`.  It requires `y length == x rows * z cols` however, which may not be possible with your data.  But maybe you can reformat it.  All surface plotting functions are going to require an xy grid with a z value for each xy value.  See `example(surface3d)`.

Comment: Or, if you must connect the points you have as is, in a mesh fashion, you could construct all possible segments between your points and then draw them with `segments3d`.  `expand.grid` might be helpful in this regard. Or try this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z)

Comment: x is 'window width' used in rollapply function, y is the results of rollaplly, z is time index.

Comment: I've done something like this before with `tripack`, constructing the Delaunay triangulation/Voronoi diagram.  At the moment I can't get it to work with these data points ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution comes to me from this thread:
[Making a wireframe plot from an x,y,z data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421211/making-a-wireframe-plot-from-an-x-y-z-data-frame)
below code will work for the sample data provided above (just switch x->y,y->z,z->x)

```
zmat <- matrix(data = z, nrow = 6, ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE)
surface3d(x = 1:6, y = c(1,3,6,9,12), z = zmat, alpha = 0.4, colour = 'blue')
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's question.  They have data that are *not* on a grid ...

Comment: the task was to plot a surface3d between those five lines, it was achieved by code above. matrix function creates a grid.

Comment: ?? but those aren't the y values that the OP gave?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @BenBolker: But MusX was the OP.

Comment: huh.  OK.  I wouldn't have thought that was the answer to the question, but I guess the OP knows best what the OP wants ...